# Dependency injection in nested dynamic object creation?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

I have a quite complex application with objects that are nested quite deep from Main and I would like to avoid passing all the dependencies down from the top-level objects and down to the bottom where it might be needed / used.

This is some sample code to illustrate, but is very simplified:

```cs
internal class Program
{
    public interface IPriceList
    {
        double GetPrice();
    }

    public class PriceList : IPriceList
    {
        public double GetPrice() { return 4.3;  }
    }

    public abstract class Condition
    {
        public abstract bool IsTrue();
    }

    public class A
    {
        private List<Condition> _conditions = new List<Condition>();
        
        public A()
        {
        }

        public void CreateConditionsFromJson()
        {
            // Read from JSON and dynamically create conditions (not as simple as below)
            _conditions.Add(new PriceIsHigherCondition(3.4, ???))
        }
    }

    public class PriceIsHigherCondition : Condition
    {
        double _price;
        IPriceList _priceLIst;

        public PriceIsHigherCondition(double price, IPriceList priceList)
        {
            _price = price;
            _priceLIst = priceList;
        }

        public override bool IsTrue()
        {
            return _price > _priceLIst.GetPrice();
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // A is not created here, but deeper down
    }
}
```

It's tempting to create a static class, set the member variables in Main and then access it in the constructors at the bottom level (the condition):

```cs
public static class ConditionDependencies
{
    public static IPriceList PriceList { get; set; }
}
```

Any more elegant solution?

Comment: Inject `IPriceList` into `A`?

Comment: A is not created from main. And IPriceList is not the only dependency. Each type of potential condition may have it's own dependency meaning that A needs the full list of dependencies. And how can dependency injection work for A if A is not instantiated from main?

Comment: Where is `A` instantiated? Could that class not provide the dependencies to `A`? Think you need to add some more code to your question, as it's difficult to answer at the moment.

Comment: Any class could provide the dependencies, but I quickly end up in a situation where tons of dependencies are passed from one class to the other. Adding one condition with a new dependency then triggers adding the new dependency to a lot of constructors and just passing them from one level to the next. Doesn't seem very elegant.

Answer (score 0):

I kind of like this (even it might be an anti-pattern):

Define a public static class for dependencies:

```
    public static class ConditionDependencies
    {
        public static IPriceList PriceList { get; set; }
    }
```

In Main, setup the dependencies:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Setup dependencies
        ConditionDependencies.PriceList = new PriceList();
    }
```

In a constructor anywhere needing a dependency, just get it:

```
    public class PriceIsHigherCondition : Condition
    {
        double _price;
        IPriceList _priceLIst;

        public PriceIsHigherCondition(double price)
        {
            // Inject Dependencies
            _priceLIst = ConditionDependencies.PriceList;

            _price = price;
        }

        public override bool IsTrue()
        {
            return _price > _priceLIst.GetPrice();
        }
    }
```

Is it an anti-pattern? Why? What are the pitfalls?